# How to create a map projection

Tags: differential-geometry, projection, map-projections

Theoretically, there are infinitely many map projections. They are usually defined by precise mathematical formulae, although so-called *comprise* maps (most notably the Robinson projection) also exist, which uses pre-defined values at specific latitudes and interpolation to calculate the exact projection.

I am more interested in the former - projections defined by mathematical formulae.
For example, the famous Mercator projection is defined by the following formulae:
$$x=R(\lambda-\lambda_0)$$ $$y=R\ln[\tan(\pi/4+\psi/2)]$$ where $\lambda$ is the longitude and $\psi$ is the latitude.

Now, there are many other "funky" map projections like the Euler spiral map projection and waterman butterfly projection below.

[image]
[image]

**How can I go about creating my own mathematically defined map projection?**

This does not have to be practical or anything, but I would just like to be able to create an original map projection since there are infinitely many.

Comment: Not sure this is a good fit for the site: Unless you have some geographic or mathematical objective (distort areas or distances or angles as little as possible, keep continents contiguous, have the result fit into a $[\sqrt{2}:1]$ rectangle, etc., etc.), the question amounts to "pick a subset of a punctured sphere and map it to the plane". (Separately, if anyone posts an example, then _you_ didn't create it originally, so in a humorously ironic way the question is impossible to answer as written. :)

Comment: That's true, if I wanted to map it to a particular shape (e.g.a $\sqrt(2):1$ rectangle), then how would I accomplish that? 
Examples are very much appreciated, as I will then know how I should be even *approaching* this problem.

Comment: First a literal answer: If we map the point at longitude $-180 < \theta < 180$ and latitude $-90 < \phi < 90$ to $(\theta, \phi)$ in the plane, we can scale the image to whatever aspect ratio we like, deform it how we like, etc. etc. And that, in a sense, is the complete story. <> Second, the underlying question feels not dissimilar to "I want to invent something. Can someone invent something so I can see how it's done?" That's not how invention works, and partly why an answer in the spirit of the question seems impossible.

Comment: What would we do (e.g. mathematical operations) to ensure that the resulting map is of a particular shape (e.g .a rectangle)?
Indeed, it may feel like I'm asking for an invention, but I thought it's a trivial one because of the fact that there are infinitely many possible projections. I'm not asking for the next ground-breaking map projection that would be used in navigation or anything, I just want to know the general process of creating one.

Comment: As for scaling a rectangle, the points $(\theta, \phi)$ as in the prior comment fill out a rectangle with aspect ratio $[2 : 1]$, so the points $(a\theta/2, b\phi)$ fill out a rectangle of aspect ratio $[a : b]$. <> In the hope it helps (though I'm not a cartographer:), the map sending $(\theta, \phi)$ to $(\theta, \sin\phi)$ (radial projection to a circumscribed cylinder) is area-preserving, and the map sending $(\theta, \phi)$ to $\frac{\cos\phi}{1 - \sin\phi}(\cos\theta, \sin\theta)$ (stereographic projection from the north pole) is angle preserving.

Comment: Thank you for the info, that definitely helps! Do you happen to know the mathematics of why those "rules" give those results (area-preserving, angle preserving)? What is the name of the relevant area of mathematics I can look up? I'm interested in the mathematics of map projections and don't yet know how they work.

Comment: "Multivariable calculus" and/or "differential geometry". <> If memory serves, Wikipedia has a decent page of geographically-interesting map projections.

Comment: Thank you, I'll look in to it.